# Whats the difference between a uniformed and non-uniformed histogram?

Tags: c++, video, graph, opencv

I am using openCV and am wondering about the diff between being uniformed or non-uniformed. 
Could someone give me a simple, NON-TECHNICAL description?

Thanks

Comment: If you find answers helpful please mark them as answers. If not please specify ways to improve them, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A uniform histogram has bins that are exactly the same size,
For example a uniform historgram from 0-10 with 2 bins would contain the bins
`{0-5} and {5-10}`
Basically the histogtram is split evenly into a certain number of bins all the same size.

A non-uniform histogram will contain bins that are not of uniform size, etc, a non uniform histogram from 0-10 with 2 bins will contain bins like
`{0-3} and {3-10}`
Basically the historgram is split unevently into bins that are not the same size.

[reference found here](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/Creating-non-uniform-histograms-td6038498.html)

Comment: A bin is basically a container, for example an array of 10 could be said to have 10 'bins', with a histogram it's usually for colours, for a histogram with 255 bins you can fit 255 colours if its one colour per bin.

Comment: Thanks :)
But wouldn't you always use uniformed bins?
I mean non-uniformed wouldn't give a proper representation of data because it would be uneven.
Why would you ever use an non-uniformed one?

Comment: if you have a really clustered histogram and needed more bins in one area you'd use more bins there and less in an area where there may be 2 colours in 20 spaces, more than likely you'd just group those 2 colours into 1 bin and save yourself 18 empty bins.

Comment: Is someone able to give a code example of how to set non-uniform bins? As Serdalis said, I have a clustered histogram where most of my values are <10 but some go up to 255.

Comment: @Mirror318 just make an array and assign things to different indexes of the array according to some function you define.